# How to implement my own ProductImpl in Broadleaf?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, broadleaf-commerce

I would like to implement my own `ProductImpl` instead of creating a new class extending the `ProductImpl`, I would like to replace the existing `ProductImpl` with my own implementation.

The thing here is that, I have added two columns to the `BLC_PRODUCT` table additionally. Now, I would like to re-design the `ProductImpl` class containing those two columns.

So, I have written a class called `MyProductImpl` which looks like this..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BLC_PRODUCT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
//multi-column indexes don't appear to get exported correctly when declared at the field level, so declaring here as a workaround
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "BLC_PRODUCT", indexes = {
  @Index(name = "PRODUCT_URL_INDEX",
          columnNames = {"URL","URL_KEY"}
  )
})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="blProducts")
@AdminPresentationClass(populateToOneFields = PopulateToOneFieldsEnum.TRUE, friendlyName = "baseProduct")
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE BLC_PRODUCT SET ARCHIVED = 'Y' WHERE PRODUCT_ID = ?")
@DirectCopyTransform({
      @DirectCopyTransformMember(templateTokens = DirectCopyTransformTypes.SANDBOX, skipOverlaps=true),
      @DirectCopyTransformMember(templateTokens = DirectCopyTransformTypes.SANDBOX_PRODUCT_INVOKE),
      @DirectCopyTransformMember(templateTokens = DirectCopyTransformTypes.MULTITENANT_CATALOG)
})
public class MyProductImpl implements Product, Status, AdminMainEntity, Locatable
{
// all the code from ProductImpl pasted here..
@Column(name="MY_CLASS_ID")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = MyClass.class)
protected MyClass myclass;

@Column(name="MY_CLAZZ_ID")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = MyClazz.class)
protected MyClazz myclazz;

}
```

Here, the setter method isn't called when I am creating a new product via admin interface but the values are injected (except to my additional fields).
The values to these additional fields should actually be inserted in the program internally, instead of direct input from the user. How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using boradleaf 3.1.x.

So I will give you a short idea about how you could inject custom relations from the backend.

You can take as an example `org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.SkuCustomPersistenceHandler`

You should implement desired methods like :  `org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.SkuCustomPersistenceHandler#canHandleAdd`
or
`org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.SkuCustomPersistenceHandler#canHandleUpdate`

after that you should implement methods like :

`org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.SkuCustomPersistenceHandler#add`
and

`org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.SkuCustomPersistenceHandler#update`

If this ins't what you wanted, please feel free to ask for additional details.